# Процессы в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, vps, vds

На сайте под Joomla, пытаюсь запустить компонент, но он пишет что недостаточно прав для чтения файла, однако в менеджере через ftp я установил на все что можно права - 777. В тех поддержке сказали, что возможно проблема в том, что процессы на сервере запускаются от одного пользователя, а папки и файлы принадлежат другому.

Скажите, как можно посмотреть список процессов и их владельца, а также как его сменить на другого владельца, с помощью каких команд?

Comment: 777 если третья цифра 7 - то все пользователи имеют право на чтение/запись/исполнение. На конкретно тот файл, который не может прочитаться, права тоже выставлены? `ps axu | grep 'процесс'` - находите процесс и первая колонка USER - владелец процесса.

Comment: Я же говорю, что на все выставлены права 777, посмотрел список процессов, там root и www-data пользователи от которых запущены процессы. Что делать в таком случае, потому что компоненты очень необходимы для сайта?

Comment: Убедитесь, что у вас соответствующие права по всему пути до файла, на всех папках. И потом не помешало бы их понизить до минимально рабочих

Comment: Добавьте пользователя в группу `www-data`:`sudo usermod -a -G www-data $(id -un)`

Comment: Да я же говорю что дело не в правах на папки. Что-то в настройках сервера. Потому что до переустановки системы, стояли права такие же на папках, а все работало прекрасно. Что по поводу процессов, как изменить пользователя от которого они запускаются?

Comment: www-data:sudo usermod -a -G www-data $(id -un) Command not found

Comment: Вы точно проверили ВСЕ папки? Например, если joomla лежит в /var/www/joomla, то надо проверить и /var, и /var/www, и /var/www/joomla

Comment: *недостаточно прав для чтения файла* — какого именно файла, при этом сообщается?